# What's the equivalent of z-index (arrange order) send to back / bring to front with Slides API?

Tags: google-slides-api

I am calling the slides API and retrieving multiple shape elements on a slide.  These shapes are on top of each other, so only the one is visible.  Is there a way from the API of telling which element is "visible" and in front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of `PageElement` objects returned in `Page.pageElements` should be ordered by z-index, from back to front. I dont see this mentioned in the API docs, but you should be able to verify it yourself by playing with a few shapes in the Slides editor and checking the order they are returned by the API.

Comment: Great answer thank you.  I willl try a couple of experiments as you suggest.  A quick try shows your theory to be correct.  I will come back and post my detailed findings.   This answer came very quickly and changed my mindset from being completely stuck to seeing a likely way forward.   Actually very useful coming back with a really good, credible pointer in the right direction and doing so quickly.

Comment: I created a Google slides presentation, with one blank slide.  Then added a small square and filled it with colour green.   Then did the same for blue and red and placed them all on top of each other.  I experimented with all combinations of selecting a square, then move back, or move to back and always the visible square (the one at front) appears last in the pageElement array.