# Bring to Front or Z-Index for Slides API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

Is there a function or request in the Slides API that manipulates the z-index of an object based on an objectId? I would like to send an object to the front of all other objects on a slide. I'm using google apps script. I saw a question on how to see the orientation that objects are layered, but I have not found a way to manipulate these object's z-index.

edit: I tried the following and was not successful:

```
var shapeArray = SlidesApp.openById(presentationCopyId).getSlides()[5].getShapes();
shapeArray.splice(shapeArray.length - 1, 0, shapeArray.splice(2,1)[0]);
```

Comment: Slides REST API (the advanced service, `Slides.<stuff>`) or the Slides Service (via `SlidesApp`)? Both are available in Apps Script. Have you tried reordering the relevant object arrays?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123546/whats-the-equivalent-of-z-index-arrange-order-send-to-back-bring-to-front-w

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of z-index (arrange order) send to back / bring to front with Slides API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123546/whats-the-equivalent-of-z-index-arrange-order-send-to-back-bring-to-front-w)

Comment: @tehhowch I believe via SlidesApp. Im unaware of how to reorder the relevant object arrays, could you point me in the right direction? This is not a duplicate of the other post, as the other post does not describe how to manipulate the z-index, only how to find what the current index is

Comment: Via the Slides Service you can't perform such a rearrangement. With the Slides API, you can alter the quantity they refer to in the duplicate answer. The methods available will depend on the language you are using, search the internet for `<language> reorder list elements`. In JavaScript, "lists" are better known as `Array`s. Review the [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) to get started and learn the environment.

Answer (score 1):

As of **November 2018** you can use new Shape's [`bringToFront()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#bringtofront) method:

```
var shapeArray = SlidesApp.openById(presentationCopyId).getSlides()[5].getShapes();

var shapeToMoveToFront = shapeArray[0];

// send object to the front
shapeToMoveToFront.bringToFront();
```

---

List of all new methods that let you control the Z-positioning of page elements in Slides:

- `bringForward()`
- `bringToFront()`
- `sendBackward()`
- `sendToBack()`

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes